# Termination Character in Suffix Trees

Tags: python, suffix-trees

I am trying to create a generalised suffix tree from a very large number of strings using Ukkonen's algorithm, however I run out of unique symbols to use as string termination characters.

I was wondering whether there is any way to work around this problem? For example, would it be possible to mark string ends as integers and when the integer grows to a multi digit value, still interpret that value as a single character.

Any input would be appreciated,
thanks !